# Laravel 5 redirect after store

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-routing

How to redirect a route after store process at L5 ?

My route is

```
Route::get('/pages/aracislemler/{id}', ['middleware' => ['roles'], 'uses' => 'PagesController@aracislemler', 'roles' => ['Admin']]);
```

And controller function

```
public function store()
{

        $brand_name = Request::get('brand_id');
        $type_id = Request::get('type_id');
        //$client_id = Request::get('representive_client_id');

        if (!Brand::find($brand_name)) {
            $brand = new Brand;
            $brand -> brand_name = $brand_name;
            $brand -> type_id = $type_id;
            $brand -> save();

            $last_brand_id = $brand -> id;

            $input = Request::except('brand_id');
            Vehicle::create($input);

            $vehicle = Vehicle::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
            $vehicle -> update(array('brand_id' => $last_brand_id));

        }else{         
            $input = Request::all();
            Vehicle::create($input);
        }

        return  redirect('pages/aracislemler');
}
```

Comment: Do you want to go back to the same ID?

Comment: @ThomasSnijder i want to go to last inserted record

Comment: You can append the ID of the last record in the redirect URL like this. return  redirect('pages/aracislemler/' . $ID); replace $ID with the correct variable containing the last id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to redirect to record that was created/updated , you should change:

```
Vehicle::create($input);
```

into:

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::create($input);
```

and now:

```
return redirect('pages/aracislemler');
```

into

```
return redirect('pages/aracislemler/'.$vehicle->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

**My route:**

```
Route::resource('portal', 'PortalController');
Route::resource('show', 'PortalController');
```

**PortalController: (Store Function)**

```
$portalNewID = $portal->id; //I retrieved the last ID
return redirect('portal/'.$portalNewID); //This will redirect to the latest page you just created
```

Hope it helps.